I loaded zImage ,dtb from usb 1st partition and rootfs from 2nd partition but when i tried start the linux system it is getting stuck
=> ext4load usb 0:1 $kernel_addr_r zImage
9460560 bytes read in 7026 ms (1.3 MiB/s)
=> ext4load usb 0:1 $fdt_addr_r imx6sx-sdb.dtb
49228 bytes read in 112 ms (428.7 KiB/s)
=> bootz $kernel_addr_r - $fdt_addr_r
Kernel image @ 0x12000000 [ 0x000000 - 0x905b50 ]
Flattened Device Tree blob at 18000000
Booting using the fdt blob at 0x18000000
Working FDT set to 18000000
Error: ethernet@2188000 No valid MAC address found.
Error: ethernet@2188000 No valid MAC address found.
Using Device Tree in place at 18000000, end 1800f04b
Working FDT set to 18000000
Starting kernel ...
